# Python Mixin for __str__and Method Resolution Order

Tags: python, mixins

I find that many classes I write in Python contain a small set of variables I actually would like to see when I call `str()`, and that rewriting `__str__(self)` for each is rather cumbersome.  Thus, I cooked up the following mixin,

```
class StrMixin(object):
  '''
  Automatically generate __str__ and __repr__
  '''
  def __str__(self):
    import types
    name = self.__class__.__name__ + ': '
    attrs = [ '{}={}'.format(k,v) for (k,v) in self.__dict__.items() ]
    return name + ', '.join(attrs)

  def __repr__(self):
    return str(self)
```

However, if I write a class,

```
class C(object, StrMixin):
    pass
```

I get the following error on instantiation,

```
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    Cannot create a consistent method resolution
order (MRO) for bases object, StrMixin
```

Granted, including `object` here is redundant, but what's really going on here?

Comment: If you just want to work around this, consider making a decorator instead of a mixin.

Answer (score 11):

When you define:

```
class StrMixin(object):
  ...
```

The compiler knows that `StrMixin` comes before `object` in the class's MRO.

When you do:

```
class C(object, StrMixin):
    pass
```

You have told the compiler that `object` comes before `StrMixin` in the MRO. But `object` also has to come after `StrMixin` so it would have to appear twice in the MRO and that isn't allowed.

If you say:

```
class C(StrMixin, object):
    pass
```

then the MRO is simply `C`, `StrMixin`, `object` which satisfies the ordering imposed by both classes. There is no duplication because although `object` is referenced twice there is no conflict between the definitions.

Comment: +1. Your answer is much cleared than mine, so I did not even bother correcting my mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

You answered the question yourself - the second `object` is redundant.  Class C has two bases: object and StrMixin.  However, StrMixin's base is also object, so its gets confused as to which object it should resolve first.  The MRO is calculates it as (C, STRMixin, object, object), which has duplicate objects.  In this particular case it seems obvious what the solution should be, but add a few more classes and the MRO could become much less clear.  E.g.

```
class A(object):
    pass
class B(object, A):
    pass
class C(object, A):
    pass
class D(object, B, C):
    pass
class E(object, A, D):
    pass
```

What is the MRO for E?  Whatever it is, its really complicated, has duplicates and probably a few loops.

MRO is explained quite well [here](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/), and your specific case is dealt with about two thirds down the page, the first example under "Bad Method Resolution Orders".

Comment: Could you clarify "object comes StrMixin comes after object"?

Comment: Actually, duplicates are no problem, since Python's MRO algorithm will remove those.  IIRC, the MRO algorithm has not changed at all in Python 3, and the OP's sample code produces the same error in 3.2.

Comment: Its a rather confusing subject, but I hope this is clearer now.

Comment: @Ferdinand - I wasn't sure whether they'd changed the MRO in Python3, obviously I was wrong about that, so the code would then still produce the same error in 3.2.  I don't think the MRO does remove duplicates.  How would it know which to remove?

Comment: @aquavitae It will remove duplicate provided it can do so unambiguously. In this case the class definition told it that `object` comes in front of `StrMixin` in the MRO, but `StrMixin` tells the compiler that `object` comes after `StrMixin`. There is no logical ordering that satisfies both of these.

Comment: @Duncan - That's what I meant to say. I just didn't explain it well in my comment.  The link I've added to the answer explains it well.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple inheritance can be mind-bending. To keep inheritance simple while using mixins, you can define the function outside the class and assign it into the class when you define it.

```
class StrMixin:     # class here used only as a namespace

    @staticmethod   # not needed with Python 3
    def __str__(self):
        name = self.__class__.__name__ + ': '
        attrs = [ '{}={}'.format(k,v) for (k,v) in self.__dict__.items() ]
        return name + ', '.join(attrs)
    __repr__ = __str__

class C(object):
    __str__, __repr__ = StrMixin.__str__, StrMixin.__repr__
```

Or if you store your mixin functions in a module, then you can use it in your class like so:

```
class C(object):
    from StrMixin import __str__, __repr__
```